# Как сделать фон мозайкой?

Tags: css

Подскажите, как создать фон, чтобы при прокрутке фон сливался?
А сейчас получается, что верхний край изображения фона светлее, чем нижний, и при прокрутке видно границу фона.
https://jsfiddle.net/1rvurue4/
Можно ли как-то разрезать картинку, чтобы фон сливался?
Может быть сделать как-то с помощью svg, но чтобы было похоже.

```css
.wrapper{
  background-image: url(http://hvac-profi.com/pic/bg.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Нужно в фотошопе снять слой, который создает затемнение и сделать картинку без него.

Comment: Ну, эм, возьмите да разрежьте в фотошопе как вам надо :)

Comment: @Sasha Omelchenko, так а если нет отдельного слоя затемнения. Фон сейчас в виде одной картинки

Comment: @andreymal, ну так если бы я знал, как правильно разрезать, я бы не задавал этот вопрос

Comment: @word значит эту задачу нужно адресовать дизайнеру. По всей видимости, если вы задаете этот вопрос, то самому вам не справиться.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/daniel217/hcw1zh81/1/ вот так вот можно

Comment: В качестве эксперимента попробовал разделить фон на две части: шестиугольники и шум поверх них — так, чтобы шестиугольники двигались при прокрутке, а шум не двигался. Получилась хрень, но поделюсь забавы ради https://jsfiddle.net/1s2wc11n/ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-image: url("https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2017/08/013d883b245dddf06388cd27dac6ca7c.jpg");
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Вариант № 1.

Вырезать один шестиугольник и повторить те стили что вы уже сделали. Получите однородный фон из **одинаковых** шестиугольников.

Вариант № 2
Подредактировать исходное изображение так что бы его верх и низ совпадали. Получите фон из **разных** шестиугольников идущих как бы полосами.

Вопрос скорее в том, какой результат требуется, от этого и отталкивайтесь.

П.С. Цсс не умеет анализировать картинки так что просто с помощтю стилей это не решить. В любом случае прийдется менять саму картинку.

Comment: можно уточнить по первому варианту? Ну вырезал я шестиугольник, что с ним делать дальше? Какие стили имеются ввиду?

Comment: У вас есть стили для класса wrapper. примените их же но урл картинки должен смотреть не на сетку шестиугольников а на один. Кстати, если у вас эта картинка фоном для всей страницы можно использовать не div а body (если я не ошибаюсь)

Comment: мозайкой не получилось сделать. Вырезал один шестиугольник, фон получился решеткой. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать мозайкой?

Comment: @word Вырезайте не по форме шестиугольника а квадратом где вершины квадрата находятся в в середине соседних шестигранников. Сейчас попробую куда то выложить мою версию.